# Domino DB View.AllEntries takes ages

Tags: database, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, labview

as the title says: I just want to get the first 10 entries of a Notes Domino DB like the SQL Statement "Limits" - foolishly using labview.

Therefore I create an IDatabase Object, accessing via GetView. This returns an IView Object and is valid. For getting an IViewEntryCollection, I have to run the AllEntries property but this takes ages... I thought I'd get just a pointer object which I can enumerate by ViewEntry.ColumnValues and ViewEntryCollection.GetNextEntry.

Is there an other method instead of using the View.AllEntries call? However, retrieving all database entries seems for me as a little overkill if I just want to have the first 10 entries.

Thanks a lot,

AllDayPiano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the view object you can create a ViewNavigator object.  The view navigator has methods that let you iterate in order with GetFirst and GetNext methods.

Comment: I tried to connect an ViewNavigator method node to the Reference returned by the GetView Method but this doesn't work. It's changing the object type to an IView Object. I have absolutely no idea how I can handle this. Sometimes Labview is some really moldy piece of cake.

Comment: Oh well, I figured out how this has to be done. However, it hangs at the ViewNavigator.Count call. Why?

Comment: For anyone who will read this: I gave up trying to use any of the available Count methods. I'm just asking for a valid Reference and by means of this seeing if there's an entry in the list. Thanks to Ken for his good hint.